# How close can a moon orbit a planet?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, moons, astronomy

On an Earth-like planet, can I have a natural satellite in a stable orbit so low that it shares an atmosphere with the planet?

Comment: Unfortunately the moon wouldn't even be able to get that close to a planet in the first place, on account of the [Roche Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit).  Basically, large satellites get torn apart by gravitational forces if they orbit too close.

Comment: Similar questions was already asked and answered on astronomy stack.

Comment: I haven't read the linked questions in full, but I want to point out that this question may not be a duplicate as it A) Doesn't specify a planet type. B) Asks "how close?" as well as "can it be this close?" But I'd have to check the others to be sure.

Comment: The size of the satellites is indeed largely irrelevant. They should be visible from the ground, though.

Comment: @Era The question within the body does not ask about general proximity, it asks if the two bodies could share the atmosphere. That question has been answered in two ways.

Answer (score 8):

No, if it shares an atmosphere with the planet then air friction will quickly cause its orbit to decay and it will crash into the planet. That’s why satellite orbits decay.